# Chrome extension browser action popup jitter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am developing a chrome extension and I am trying to animate the size of the popup via javascript. I am using webkitRequestAnimationFrame on window load to accomplish this.

The resizing works as expected, but I am seeing an issue. Sometimes the popup jitters during resize (the right margin especially). I also notice that the small triangle anchor that tethers it to the extension icon in the toolbar is moving left and right at the same time.

Is this some sort of auto-adjust related to how chrome decides where to anchor the popup, or am I doing something wrong? It only happens sometimes.

Thanks.

EDIT 1
Using chrome 34.0.1847.11 dev-m

EDIT 2

```
function animate (element, property, destination, duration, easing, callback) {
    // defaults
    easing   = easings[easing] || easings.linear;
    callback = callback || (typeof easing === 'function' ? easing : undefined);

    // setup
    var b = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element)[property]),
        d = duration,
        v = parseFloat(destination),
        c = v - b,
        end;

    // find value type
    var suffix = destination.toString().replace(v, '');

    // animation step

    var step = function (t) {
        if (!end)
           end = d + t;

        if (t < end) {
           webkitRequestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
           t = end;
           callback.call();
        }

        // set new value
        element.style[property] = easing(d - end + t, b, c, d) + suffix;
    };

    // start animating
    webkitRequestAnimationFrame(step);
}

animate(d.body, 'width', '300px', 200);
```

Comment: It's hard to guess code behavior without the code. Post it!

Comment: sorry, added some code to go with my issue :p